# cordova Error: Cannot read property 'prepare' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova

When you run cordova run browser --live-reload, 
the browser opens, but when you save index.html, 
localhost shuts down with the error "Error: Cannot read property 'prepare' of undefined." How do I fix it?

Comment: Anything on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have to run browser --live-reload every time, cordova-plugin-browsersync not working in this case